# Find the closest entry based on timestamp

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with entries about the weather every 20 minutes. For example, this would be the timestamp column:

```
2007-01-01 00:00:00
2007-01-01 00:20:00
```

And so on. Now if I have another timestamp, for example `2007-01-01 00:07:53`, how can I find the entry within the weather table that is closest to this specific timestamp?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you only ever want to have a single row, you can do something like this:

```
select *
from the_table
order by abs(extract(epoch from (the_timestamp_column - timestamp '2007-01-01 00:07:53')))
limit 1
```

The abs(...) is there to deal with timestamps that are bigger or smaller then the one stored in the table.

If the supplied timestamp is **always** bigger then the latest timestamp in the table, you can simplify that to:

```
order by timestamp '2007-01-01 00:07:53' - the_timestamp_column
```

Comment: Thank you for both solutions. The timestamp given will always be a random time in some way, therefore the first solution you posted is best in this case, as you mentioned.